# Missing Load plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

After I change some of the code from 1.3 to 2.1. Some error occur. This is the error:

```
Missing Plugin
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the forums plugin
Error: Make sure your plugin forums is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded

<?php
CakePlugin::load('forums');

Loading all plugins: If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file

CakePlugin::loadAll();
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_plugin.ctp.
```

Somebody, please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Write the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array('Forums',
   array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true),
));
```

Comment: Please Make sure your plugin forums is in the app\Plugin directory and Your plugin name should be "Forums".

Comment: Please check my Edited code( Write the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file ) : CakePlugin::loadAll(array('Forums',
   array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true),
));

Comment: Missing Plugin

Error: The application is trying to load a file from the forums plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin forums is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded

<?php
CakePlugin::load('forums');

Loading all plugins: If you wish to load all plugins at once, use the following line in your app\Config\bootstrap.php file

CakePlugin::loadAll();
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_plugin.ctp

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in cake 2+.  The problem in this was

```
 CakePlugin::load( 'DebugKit');
```

was already added in bootstrap.php file and when I added this line

```
CakePlugin::load( 'Cooltheme');
```

The first was loaded and second was omitted. So to solve this problem I simply removed second one and modified the first one as below

```
CakePlugin::load( array('DebugKit','Cooltheme'));
```

Then it works for me, may be heplfull to others.