# Cakephp Missing Plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I already upgrade my **cakephp from 1.3 to 2.0**. And I already make some changes. 
I still got this error.

> Missing Plugin
>
> Error: The application is trying to load a file from the forums plugin
>
> Error: Make sure your plugin forums is in the app\Plugin directory and
>   was loaded

```
<?php CakePlugin::load('forums');
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: DUPLICATE OF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661218/missing-load-plugin

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CakePlugin::load('Forums')
```

Comment: You NEED to to apply the 2.0 naming conventions. That means that the folder for the plugin hast to be `APP/Plugin/Forums` (note the capital F)

Answer (score 0):

add those line app\Config\bootstrap.php file

```
 CakePlugin::loadAll(array('Forums',
    array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true),
 ));
```

Comment: Do I need to rename the folder forum or forums? As in make it into capital letters for the first letter???