# missing Load plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I already upgrade my cakephp in to the latest one. I also already make some changes due to the migration. But I have this error

Missing Plugin

Error: The application is trying to load a file from the forums plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin forums is in the app\Plugin directory and was loaded

someone please help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where are your plugin file(s) located?  What relevant code do you have so far?  ...etc etc.

Comment: My file C:\xampp\htdocs\hedesu2\app\Plugin\forums. I also already use the new migration code. Such as $this->request->data. at the cakephp blog, its said that i need to chnage the file name. but i didn;t under stand

Comment: have you load the plugin from bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you load the plugin from bootstrap.
`CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once`
`CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit`

Comment: for those following this advice it works but make sure the directories name of the plugin is correct "DebugKit" and not debug-kit-master or something like that.

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661218/missing-load-plugin/26662343#26662343) may be useful for you.